# How to override default AWS EventBridge event name when deploying with Serverless Framework?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, aws-event-bridge

I'm deploying a Lambda function via Serverless Framework, and the function is going to have multiple EventBridge events (schedules) tied to it. For this reason, I would like to create a custom name for each schedule to easily differentiate them from each other. The problem is that adding in a "name" propery to the event objects doesn't seem to be doing anything because the events are still being deployed with default names.

I have setup my Serverless file exactly how they have it setup in the documentation:

```
functions:
  myFunction:
    handler: index.handler
    events:
      - eventBridge:
          name: event-bridge-custom-name
          schedule: rate(10 minutes)
          input:
            key1: value1
```

[Link to documentation](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/event-bridge).

Instead of my EventBridge rule being deployed as "event-bridge-custom-name", it's deployed as "myapp-rule-1", "myapp-rule-2", etc.

Comment: Looks like the feature got fixed only yesterday, not yet released as per this github issue https://github.com/serverless/serverless/pull/11690

Comment: What a coincidence, thanks @VikramS!